# What is the difference when adding a childview to parent using inflate with parent and attachToRoot true or calling addView()?

Tags: android, android-view, android-inflate

I have a FrameLayout and I need to programmatically inflate child view 
I tried this `layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, frameLayout,true)`

and I tried this `View childView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, frameLayout ,false)
frameLayout.addView(childView)`

and there is also this one `View childView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout,null)
frameLayout.addView(childView)`

It gives the same result I am wondering which one it right to use ? what is the difference ?

Comment: The first two are equivalent. If you pass `true` for `attachToRoot`, the `LayoutInflater` does the simple `addView()` for you. The last one is different from the first two, though, in that `LayoutInflater` doesn't have the parent `View` with which to generate the appropriate `LayoutParams` from any `layout_*` attributes you might have in the XML. In that case, when you `addView()`, the default `LayoutParams` are used, and any `layout_*` attributes are basically lost.

Comment: Thank you but I don't get the explanation 
What do you mean layout_* child or parent layout? and in which case layout losing layoutParams in the last case when adding view?